# Clustering Scikit - Convert Business Data to machine learning input data

Tags: algorithm, machine-learning, scikit-learn, cluster-analysis, data-science

I am new to world of data science and am trying to understand the concepts on the outcomes of the the ML. I have started off to use **scikit - clustering** example. Using the scikit library is well documented everywhere. But all the examples go with the assumption of ready numerical data.

Now how does a data scientist convert a business data into machine learning data. Just to give an example, here is a customer and sales data I have prepared..

[image: Customer Data]

[image: Order Data]

The first picture shows the customer data with some parameters having an integer, string and boolean values

The second picture shows the historical sales data for those customers.

Now how does such a real business data gets translated to feed to a Machine Learning algorithm? How do I convert each data to a common factor which the algorithm can understand?

Thanks
K

Answer (score 0):

Technicaly, there are many ways, such as one-hot encoding, standardization, and going into logspace for skewed attributes.

But the problem is *not* just of a technical nature.

Finding *a way* is not enough, but **you need to find one that works *really well* for your problem**. This is usually very different from problem to another. There is no "turn key solution".

Comment: Thanks @Antony-Mousse. Is there any place where I can read up these techniques? may be with some examples? I understand this is a complex topic and needs some exp to do this..

Answer (score 0):

Just addition to comment by @Anony-Mousse, you can convert Won/Lost column to value 1, 0 (e.g. 1 for `Won`, 0 for `Lost`). For `Y` column, suppose you have 3 unique values in the column, you can convert `A` to says `[1, 0, 0]` and `B` to `[0, 1, 0]` and `C` to `[0, 0, 1]` (called one-hot encoding). Same on `Z` column, you can convert `TRUE` column to `1` and `FALSE` to `0` (or `True` or `False` respectively).

To merge 2 table or excel file together, you can use additional library called `pandas` which allows you to merge two dataframe together e.g. `df1.merge(df2, on='CustID', how='left')`. Now, you can put your feature set to scikit learn properly.

Comment: Thanks! The example I gave was a random one.. In a real bus system, I have many such features, which needs to be translated into before it is fed to scikit. Is there a starting point from where I can learn these tricks?

Comment: I would say it's a mix combination of book and code documentation. My favorite machine learning book will be Pattern Recognition and Machine Learning by Bishop. After reading, you will know some basic machine learning terminology and now can search things on Google or documentation. For documentation, if I want to do one-hot encoding, I will go to see directly on scikit learn's page http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.preprocessing.OneHotEncoder.html. A lot of good example is also on a site like Kaggle where people tackle machine learning problem :)